# how to request a certain route having prefix as base route from any page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Suppose I am on a page having URL localhost/group/123, when i request a route "profile" from that page the URL looks like this localhost/group/profile. But I don't want this, i want the URL to be like this localhost/profile. When i request the "profile" route, it must be look like as localhost/profile.

When i request the profile route from the base route then that URL is what I want to be made as i request for this route from anywhere on my website. This is the route that i make in routes. I have tried prefixes but it don't work for me

```
Route::get('profile',[
           'as'=>'tech',
           function(){ echo 'tech'; }
       ] );
```

I have searched on other forms that how to resolve it but I can't find a solution.I am very confused that how to resolve it.

Comment: Use `'/profile'` instead of `'profile'`?? (Which shouldn't be neccessary) How do you "request" that route?

Comment: i have save a anker tag with href "profile" in profile option in a menu.

Comment: Can you please paste the code of how you "request" that route in your question? If you have a href "profile" you're not using routes at all, just linking to "profile" in whatever folder you are, which explains your current behaviour

Comment: <a href="profile">profile</a>
can you plz tell that how to use route in that case. my route name is tech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `name` your route and call it via `route()` like so:

In your `web.php`:

```
Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'tech', function () {
    echo 'tech';
}]);
```

In your `.blade.php` view:

```
<a href="{{ route('tech') }}">Profile</a>
```

More on routing can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing

Comment: No problem, glad it works. (Remember to accept this as an answer, thanks)